# How to call the hidden Android method getTotalUss() using Java reflection?

Tags: java, android, reflection

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1 targeting Android API 18 (before Android KitKat 4.4, so I’m dealing with Dalvik, not ART runtime).

**My questions are:**

1. How to call the hidden Android method [getTotalUss()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/Debug.java#270) using Java 
   reflection?
2. If not possible, how to find the current process USS    (Unique Set Size) memory programmatically?

I am trying to use the code below to do that but I am getting a compiler error "Unexpected token" at the statement labelled //ERROR! below in the code.

```
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    ActivityManager.MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
    activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);

    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

    Map<Integer, String> pidMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
    for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo runningAppProcessInfo : runningAppProcesses)
    {
        pidMap.put(runningAppProcessInfo.pid, runningAppProcessInfo.processName);
    }

    Collection<Integer> keys = pidMap.keySet();
    int id= android.os.Process.myPid();
    for(int key : keys)
    {
        if (key != id) continue;
        int pids[] = new int[1];
        int Uss;
        pids[0] = key;
        android.os.Debug.MemoryInfo[] memoryInfoArray = activityManager.getProcessMemoryInfo(pids);
        for(android.os.Debug.MemoryInfo pidMemoryInfo: memoryInfoArray)
        {
            try {

                Class c;
                c = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityManager");
                Method m = c.getMethod("getTotalUss", null);
                Uss = m.invoke(null,int); //             << == ERROR!
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            }
            catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            }

            System.out.println("** Uss =  " +  Uss);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling getMethod() on the ActivityManager class which doesn't contain a getTotalUss() method. That's why you're getting the error.

Instead, you'll want to reflectively get the method from the MemoryInfo class which has the getTotalUss() method. You'll also want to be sure to pass pidMemoryInfo as the receiver to the invoke() call. It's like calling pidMemoryInfo.getTotalUss().

```
Method m = android.os.Debug.MemoryInfo.class.getMethod("getTotalUss", null);
totalUss = (int) m.invoke(pidMemoryInfo,(Object[]) null);
```

See the documentation on Method's [invoke()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...)) for more details.

Comment: When I try your code, I get zero totalUss. totalUss should give the memory space allocated to the current running process.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? Try logging the exception in the catch block. It might give you some ideas.